# How to write a program using Numpy to generate and print 5 random number between 0 & 1

Tags: python, numpy, random

How to write a program using Numpy to generate and print 5 random number between 0 and 1

Comment: A quickstart tutorial is [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/quickstart.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
numbers = np.random.rand(5)
print(numbers)
```

[np.random.rand](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.rand.html) will produce a sample from the uniform distribution over [0,1]

If you want to generate numbers from a different interval, let's say [a,b] , you can use:

```
import numpy as np

a = 2
b = 4
numbers = a + np.random.rand(5)*(b-a)
print(numbers)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but does it generate numbers just between 0 and 1 ???

Comment: if i want to generate numbers between 2 and 4 for example what I should write >